# How to slice from a multi-dimensional array along an axis in NumPy?

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a NumPy ndarray `x` of shape `(n,) + higher_dims`, where `n` is a positive int and `higher_dims` is a tuple of positive ints of any length.
That is, `n` is the size of the first axis, and there can be arbitrarily many axes.

Suppose I also have an ndarray `indices` of shape `(k,) + higher_dims`, where `k` is a positive int.
That is, `indices` has the same shape as `x` except for possibly the first axis.
Assume that every entry of `indices` is an int between `0` and `n - 1`.

I want to create an array `y` that has the same shape as `indices` and that satisfies

```
y[i, ...] = x[indices[i, ...], ...]
```

for each `i` between `0` and `n - 1`. Here `...` signifies an arbitrary combination of indices for the remaining axes, not an [Ellipsis object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#Ellipsis).

For example, here is how I could create `y` if `x` is three-dimensional using for-loops:

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(24).reshape((4, 2, 3))
print('x =', x, sep='\n')

indices = np.asarray([[[1, 0, 1], [2, 1, 2]], [[3, 1, 2], [0, 0, 1]]])
print('indices =', indices, sep='\n')

y = np.empty(indices.shape, dtype=x.dtype)
for i in range(indices.shape[0]):
    for j in range(indices.shape[1]):
        for k in range(indices.shape[2]):
            y[i, j, k] = x[indices[i, j, k], j, k]  # Defining property of y
print('y =', y, sep='\n')
```

Output:

```
x =
[[[ 0  1  2]
  [ 3  4  5]]
 [[ 6  7  8]
  [ 9 10 11]]
 [[12 13 14]
  [15 16 17]]
 [[18 19 20]
  [21 22 23]]]
indices =
[[[1 0 1]
  [2 1 2]]
 [[3 1 2]
  [0 0 1]]]
y =
[[[ 6  1  8]
  [15 10 17]]
 [[18  7 14]
  [ 3  4 11]]]
```

> I am looking for a function or indexing trick to achieve this behavior in general (for ndarrays of arbitrary dimension), *without Python loops if possible*.

Comment: Simply use `np.take_along_axis(x,indices,axis=0)`.

Comment: @Divakar thank you, that's exactly what I needed! I knew about [`take()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html), but not about [`take_along_axis()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take_along_axis.html) :)